# Excel data conversion

Tags: excel

How do I convert Table 1 to Table 2 in Excel based on Column A? (Column A is the key).

Table 1:

```
|A|B|C|
|1|X| |
|1| |Y|
|2|U| |
|2| |V|
```

Table 2:

```
|A|B|C|
|1|X|Y|
|2|U|V|
```

Comment: Array formulas or SUMPRODUCT: See [Charley Kyd/ExcelUser.com: SUMPRODUCT #1](http://www.exceluser.com/explore/sumproduct_11.htm) and [Charley Kyd/ExcelUser.com: SUMPRODUCT #2](http://www.exceluser.com/explore/sumproduct_12.htm) and [Charley Kyd/ExcelUser.com](http://exceluser.com/explore/summaries.htm). Then once you have tried it out, we can help some more.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, assuming the data is regular like that, the easiest and fastest way, although certainly not the most clean one, would be an indirect.

Assuming your data starts in columns A1:C1 and you want your new table starting in E1:G1, then

E1: `=INDIRECT("A"&ROW(D1)*2)`

F1: `=INDIRECT("B"&ROW(D1)*2-1)`

G1: `=INDIRECT("c"&ROW(D1)*2)`

That doesn't generalize to "taking all empty values out of the range", but for your example it works.